# Not able to start Datastax Cassandra due to missing SystemInfo class

Tags: datastax, datastax-startup

I have installed Datastax Cassandra 5.0.4 on my mac but when i try to start, it is giving me error for SystemInfo class.

Here is related log:

Exception (com.google.inject.ProvisionException) encountered during startup: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/hadoop/hive/util/SystemInfo
  at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin.(HiveMetaStorePlugin.java:39)
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseHiveModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.DseModule -> com.datastax.bdp.DseAnalyticsModule -> com.datastax.bdp.DseHiveModule)
  while locating com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin

1 error
com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Unable to provision, see the following errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/hadoop/hive/util/SystemInfo
  at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin.(HiveMetaStorePlugin.java:39)
  at com.datastax.bdp.DseHiveModule.configure(Unknown Source) (via modules: com.datastax.bdp.DseModule -> com.datastax.bdp.DseAnalyticsModule -> com.datastax.bdp.DseHiveModule)
  while locating com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$2.get(InjectorImpl.java:1025)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1051)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.register(PluginManager.java:139)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.PluginManager.postSetup(PluginManager.java:68)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.postSetup(DseDaemon.java:824)
    at com.datastax.bdp.server.DseDaemon.setup(DseDaemon.java:447)
    at org.apache.cassandra.service.CassandraDaemon.activate(CassandraDaemon.java:568)
    at com.datastax.bdp.DseModule.main(DseModule.java:91)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/datastax/hadoop/hive/util/SystemInfo
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin.(HiveMetaStorePlugin.java:40)
    at com.datastax.bdp.plugin.HiveMetaStorePlugin$$FastClassByGuice$$7e2893c3.newInstance()
    at com.google.inject.internal.cglib.reflect.$FastConstructor.newInstance(FastConstructor.java:40)

Comment: Can I ask you to contact your startup program SA team with the full output log and system log?

Comment: I was able to find solution for this, it is expecting HIVE related environment variables set before i can start DSE cassandra.

Comment: Hey @Shailesh would you mind writing up your solution as an answer for the future?

Comment: Sorry for late reply. I added following in my .bash_profile. `code`export DSE_HOME=/Users/shailesh/dse
export HIVE_HOME=$DSE_HOME/resources/hive/
export HIVE_CONF_DIR=$HIVE_HOME/conf `code`